# dma_alloc_coherent() memory allocation failure with more than 4mb

Tags: linux, memory-management, embedded-linux

I am trying to allocate a 5-page-800x600 frame buffer(roughly 5mb). But during DRAM memory map initialization, dma_alloc_coherent() only returns a zero pointer or does not allocate the buffer.
It used to work with just allocating a 4-page frame buffer(4mb). I have already tried setting CONSISTENT_DMA_SIZE to 8mb, 10mb, and 12mb. But this doesn't seem to have any effect.
Is there any other setting I'm over looking?

thanks alot,

nazekimi

P.S.
working on a Linux 2.6.10 Mobilinux kernel

Answer (score 2):

kernel does power-of-2 allocation. so 5MB means 8MB allocation.  so probably you need to increase CONSISTENT_DMA_SIZE even more.

Thx,
Jeffrey